# Weird behaviour of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I know, this is probably not the right place for this, but I'm not sure if this is just standard behaviour or a bug.

Why does my Eclipse just closes itself all the time? It's not a crash, but whenever I click on cancel in a dialogue winnow (for example project preferences) it saves my changes and closes itself. I'm using the latest version available from Ubuntu 13.10 repositories (3.8).

Comment: The eclipse from the ubuntu repositories is hopelessly outdated. Download it from the eclipse website. The latest version is 4.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely a bad installation. Download and install the latest version from [downloads @ Eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)